# Circular Deadlock in Webapp with Weld CDI

Tags: java, multithreading, cdi, deadlock, weld2

I have a problem somewhere in my webapplication but I can't find a solution. I'm having a circular deadlock and they happen always at 2 beans. The resources they use though aren't shared between these two beans. I can't find a connection if not for one bean injected with Weld.

In the stacktrace I can see the lock is handled by Weld, but I don't know about the locked resource it's trying to lock (again).

Application's main package is **com.cmp.webapp**.

`com.cmp.webapp.PointOfSalesBean`, which is one of the two points of failure, is annotated `@javax.enterprise.context.ConversationBean`.

`com.cmp.webapp.GeoManager` is `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`.

`com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService` which is injected in both beans has it's scope set to Session as well.

One of the locked threads reports this:

```
http-thread-pool-8009(7) - threadId:2720 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- waiting to lock <507d8fe7> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "http-thread-pool-8009(2)" t@1375
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:101)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.GeoManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getNationByCod(GeoManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.util.WSConverter.toAnag(WSConverter.java:208)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService.getAnagById(KernelService.java:515)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getAnagraphicDataById(KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.RelationsBean.isCompany(RelationsBean.java:330)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.RelationsBean.onChangeContractor(RelationsBean.java:131)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.RelationsBean.create(RelationsBean.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9477.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:294)
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.RelationsBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.beforeSavePolizza(RelationsBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9476.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:590)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:585)
at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:69)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService.salvaPolizza(KernelService.java:1779)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.salvaPolizza(KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.UpgFacade.internalSave(UpgFacade.java:1037)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.UpgFacade.internalSave(UpgFacade.java:1003)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.UpgFacade.savePreventivo(UpgFacade.java:1103)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.UpgFacade$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.savePreventivo(UpgFacade$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.ProductionTypeBean.saveWithNoDocumentiIn(ProductionTypeBean.java:496)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.ProductionTypeBean.save(ProductionTypeBean.java:472)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.kernel.ProductionTypeBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(ProductionTypeBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9807.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:603)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(AjpProcessorTask.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- locked <520f51fb> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

Another (Thread-2) the following:

```
http-thread-pool-8009(2) - threadId:1375 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- waiting to lock <520f51fb> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "http-thread-pool-8009(7)" t@2720
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:101)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
at com.cmp.webapp.pos.PointOfSaleBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.isActive(PointOfSaleBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.wsproducer.SessionWebServiceFactory.prepareCredentials(SessionWebServiceFactory.java:148)
at com.cmp.webapp.wsproducer.SessionWebServiceFactory$1.invoke(SessionWebServiceFactory.java:200)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy707.getTable(Unknown Source)
at com.cmp.webapp.wsproducer.ServiceBase.getTable(BaseService.java:141)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService.getManagedAnagraphicTypes(ShellService.java:5496)
at com.cmp.webapp.service.KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getManagedAnagraphicTypes(KernelService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.anag.SearchAnagBean.getManagedAnagraphicTypes(SearchAnagBean.java:1287)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.anag.SearchAnagBean.initAnagraphicCategoriesByContext(SearchAnagBean.java:1248)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.anag.SearchAnagBean.costruct(SearchAnagBean.java:274)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4976.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:294)
at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:637)
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:703)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.ParameterInjectionPoint.getValueToInject(ParameterInjectionPoint.java:120)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.getParameterValues(MethodInjectionPoint.java:217)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstance(MethodInjectionPoint.java:137)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ProducerMethod$ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethod.java:136)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean$AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducerBean.java:319)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:307)
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
at com.cmp.webapp.bean.anag.SearchAnagBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.init(SearchAnagBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10468.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.util.FacesElUtils.invokeMethod(FacesElUtils.java:70)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.util.FacesElUtils.invokeMethod(FacesElUtils.java:62)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ActionExecutor.executeActions(ActionExecutor.java:56)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.processEvent(PrettyPhaseListener.java:131)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.afterPhase(PrettyPhaseListener.java:117)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:603)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:807)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(AjpProcessorTask.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- locked <507d8fe7> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

GeoManager.getNationByCod:

```
@javax.inject.Inject KernelService service;

@javax.annotation.PostConstruct
public void init() {
    provinces = service.getProvinces();
}

public OptionLabel getNationByCod(String cod) {
    if (cod== null)
        return null;
    List<OptionLabel> nations = service.getNationsList();
    OptionLabel nation = null;
    Iterator<OptionLabel> iter = nations.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext() && nation == null){
        OptionLabel tmp = iter.next();
        if (cod.equals(tmp.getCode())){
            nation = tmp;
        }
    }
    return nation;
}
```

PointOfSaleBean.isActive:

```
@javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.HttpParam("posCmp") String cmpParameter; 
@javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.HttpParam("posAgent") String agentParameter;
@javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.HttpParam("posSubAgent") String subAgentParameter;

@javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.Logged User user;
@javax.inject.Inject KernelService service;

private Stack<PointOfSaleInfo> posStack = new Stack<PointOfSaleInfo>();

@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.Current
public PointOfSaleInfo getPointOfSale() {
    if (isEnabled() && !this.stackPointOfSale.isEmpty()) {
        return this.stackPointOfSale.peek();
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return companyExists() != null && agentExists() != null;
}

public String companyExists() {
    return getPointOfSale() == null ? null : getPointOfSale().getComp();
}

public String agentExists()
    return getPointOfSale() == null ? null : getPointOfSale().getAgent();
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

KernelService:

```
@javax.inject.Named("service")
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class KernelService extends ServiceBase implements WebServiceWrapper, Serializable {

    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ServiceLoader<ServiceFactoryInterface> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ServiceFactoryInterface.class);
        setFactory(loader.iterator().next());
        getFactory().setFactory(PooledWebServiceFactory.istance());
    }

    @javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.events.BeforeSaving Event<MsgSaveInType> beforeSaveEvent;

    @javax.inject.Inject @com.cmp.webapp.annotations.Logged User user;

    @javax.inject.Inject MemoBean memoBean;

    @javax.inject.Inject PmlManagedBean pmlManagedBean;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of from Weld PoV is circular injection of beans themselves. Can you post the whole code of those CDI beans? Especially their injection points and post construct methods, assuming they have some.

Comment: @Siliarus editted just now. Added injections used in the three beans. Hope edits are of some help.

Comment: Can you add packages to your code snippets?

Comment: @JohnAment editted

Comment: How are you deploying your application? what app server? what version of weld/the app server?

Comment: It's Glassfish3, the application is in war format. Weld version 2.0.0.Final and CDI 1.0 @JohnAment

Comment: Glassfish 3 would have Weld 1.x.  AFAIK, this is an issue in that release.  Any chance you can upgrade your server to Glassfish 4? or another runtime that's more supported?

Comment: We're moving all our applications to Glassfish 5 therefore all libraries/dependencies of the project have been updated. I've managed to move forward Weld to 3.0.1.Final and CDI to 2.0 which is provided by Glassfish 5

Comment: And the issue is still present on Glassfish 5?

Comment: Not so far, but can't be sure either because these issues don't happen frequently and we don't know what causes them. And we don't yet have a production environment on GF5.